# Are Azure CDN, endpoint and DNS zones global only?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

Is it possible to set Azure CDN, endpoints and DNS zones as specific to an Azure region, or is that logically non-sensical since they are global by their nature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Azure cdn endpoints are globally and its data transfer work on local region decision taken based on the below rule

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so Azure CDN are regional but serve globally from that region? What about endpoints and DNS zones?